# Adding date or time in datetime format to another datetime

Tags: php, datetime

### WHAT I AM DOING

I want to find the difference between 2 datetime and add it to another datetime. I am only able to get the difference in **Y-m-d H:i:s** format.

### CODE

```
    $begin = new DateTime($start);
    $finish =  new DateTime($end);
    $diff = $begin->diff($finish);
    $difference = $diff->format("%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S");
```

Here I want to add `$difference` to another datetime say `$finaldate`. If its not possible is there any way of getting the difference in only minutes, then i could use `$date->modify("+$difference minutes");`

Comment: convert to time stamp using strtotime calculate difference (gives it in an int) add int to final time stamp convert time stamp back to y-m-d h:i:s

Comment: Would appreciate if its possible using DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****This is a method using DateTime:****

```
$begin = new DateTime($start);
$finish =  new DateTime($end);


$difference = $finish->format('U') - $begin->format('U');

// working version
$minutesDiff = round(($difference/60), 0);
$finalDate = new DateTime();
$finalDate->modify(sprintf('+%s minutes', $minutesDiff));
```

**edit**
added missing bracket

**edit2**
version without ->diff() method

Comment: can you provide an answer with how to obtain difference in minutes.

Comment: the new version should work with minutes, but it depends if you want the seconds completely removed or rounded

Comment: @gries: not working. I gave 2 datetimes 2013-06-26 03:00 and 2013-06-26 04:00. it returns 0.

Comment: @Avinash plz provide your full code, this code is working, also 03:00 vs. 04:00 is a difference of 1 hour. btw. what is "returning 0" ? which variable has the value 0?

Comment: @gries: I am also facing the same problem. I think its because %s gives only the seconds part of the datetime and hence $minutesDiff is returning 0

Comment: @gries: still the same problem. when i put %h instead of %s it returns 1 for avinash's example

Comment: i just tested the new version on my machine, and its working with diffrent date / time testcases

Comment: version2 worked fine. divided it by 60 to get in minutes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$begin = strtotime($start);
$finish= strtotime($end);
$diff  = $finish-$begin;
$finaldate = strtotime($finaldate)+$diff;
echo date("Y-M-D h-i-s",$finaldate);
```